# Find amount of sliding between 2 surfaces

Tags: finite-element-method, abaqus

in my project I am required to find how much two surfaces slide against each other (to see how much it'll will rub against skin). Does anyone know how I can find these results?

Thanks

Comment: Coefficient of friction values are stated for many materials, this is just to give you a start: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/amp/friction-coefficients-d_778.html

Comment: You may also want to look-up "tribology".

Answer (score 0):

Is this an undergraduate project? If so, the motion (slide) will occur only after the applied force overcomes the friction force between the two surfaces. The friction force = mass times gravitational acceleration times the coefficient of friction. Beyond that, you need to apply equations of motion, with a set of given conditions and assumptions, to find the distance of sliding, for instance.

Answer (score -1):

You can request contact displacements ('CDISP') in Field output requests.
Field output requests -> F-Output-1 -> Under the 'Contact' menu, select CDISP

In the Vizualization module, select Primary and CDISP.
This will plot the contact displacements.

Comment: Is this done by program, what is the program?